# Restrict Access to / with ACLs (CentOS)

Tags: linux, centos, access-control-list

This is a fairly simple question, and I've been struggling at great length with it for no reason, so I decided just to post the question.

I have a FTP server with a bunch of users. They are all part of a group, ftp-users. I only want them to be able to access one folder, let's call it /home/folder. Currently, all users can access / and other folders.

In theory, if I run:

```
setfacl -x g:501 /
```

that should remove all permissions for the folder /, should it not? I just tried it and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be messing with permissions on `/` what you want to do is setup your ftp server to chroot those users into `/home/folder`

Comment: and chrooting them to the folder will not allow them to move anywhere other than /home/folder? how would I do this?

Comment: @SoFLy correct to them they would see `/home/folder` as their `/` ... how to do it depends on your ftp server. Directions should be in the docs/man page.

Comment: When I setup a chroot jail, I vaguely recall that it stopped users from accessing directories inside the jail, and file permissions were wacky. Is this a regular occurrence or did I do something wrong? I changed the conf to chroot_local_user=YES and had this issue.

Comment: @SoFLy you'll have to do some more config to chroot multiple people into one directory. I suggest posting a new question with what you have already tried and the results.